# Getting exception on IBM Websphere MQ JMS connection with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

While trying to connect IBM MQ JMS queue from spring boot application , I am  getting below exception

Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0005: The specified value '' is not allowed for 'XMSC_WMQ_APPNAME'.

I have been already been referring to :
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring, but doesnt help.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The string `XMSC_WMQ_APPNAME` is the value of constant [WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/wmq/common/CommonConstants.html#WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME). The application name can be set with JMS methods `MQConnectionFactory.setAppName()`, see [APPLICATIONNAME](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111810_.htm).

For some reason the the application name does not get set. Please share your MQ connection configuration for your Spring Boot application.